# Regular expression search w/2 using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have one string as below.

> While comparing with iPhone and Samsung we can easily say that iPhone  has some extra application and features. But most of the application in iPhone are now available in Samsung also.Please look at the below comparison.
>
> Apple iPhone 8Gb with extra application and features
>   Apple iPhone 4Gb with extra application and features
>
> Samsung 8Gb with extra application and features
>   Samsung **2Gb with extra application** and features

I retrieved this string from Mysql database using regular expression.The query I have used is below.

```
SELECT description FROM item_master  WHERE description REGEXP '[[:<:]]2Gb( [^ ]+){1,3} application[[:>:]]';
```

I got this result because the above string satisfy the search criteria, Where I marked it as bold.

My question is below,Because I am new to PHP regular expression!!

I want to know the Position of **2Gb with extra application**  in the above string using PHP regular expression .

Comment: Use `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` when regex-matching in PHP and it will give you the position of the match.

Comment: Can you show me,What is php regular expression string equivalent to  [[:<:]]2Gb( [^ ]+){1,3} application[[:>:]]